# ¿Es posible hacer una consulta a partir del resultado de otra?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Necesito hacer una consulta en SQL/ACCESS y a raiz del campo de esa consulta realizar otra en esa misma tabla. ¿sería posible?

Por ejemplo, en el cuadro ejemplo de abajo necesitaría listarme todos los registros de clientes que contengan "1" en su nombre y cuyo asociado(el campo asociado se deberá buscar de nuevo en la misma tabla) está con el marcador de borrado activo.

¿Sería posible hacerlo en una única consulta? El campo cliente es único.

[image: EJEMPLO]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para lo de "que contengan 1 en su nombre" puedes usar LIKE '%1%' en una consulta

Comment: Podrias usar `INNER JOIN ` a la misma tabla.

Comment: Sí, es posible. Pero si es una consulta sobre una única tabla, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es poner dos condiciones a la consulta: WHERE (nombre like '%1%') AND (NOT asociado). Quizá las condiciones no las he acertado, pero me parece obvio que lo que estás buscando es una consulta con dos condiciones, si no es así, explícalo mejor ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, pero no es del todo así...

Es decir, debería buscar todos los elementos que contengan "1", y dentro de ellos debería irme al campo asociado para buscar si el cliente asociado está borrado o activo. En caso de estar borrado me lo debe mostrar pues se trata de un error en la BBDD. En el ejemplo que pongo debería mostrarme el cliente 111 (Pues contiene "1", y su asociado 333 está borrado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer con un **join** a la misma tabla, ya que el campo asociado es un cliente

```
select tab.cliente, tab2.borrado, tab.asociado as AsociadoBorrado from 
prueba tab
join prueba tab2 on tab.asociado = tab2.cliente
where tab.cliente like '%1%' and tab2.borrado = 1
```

Esto te trae el cliente 111 ya que el asociado 333 está borrado.

Lo puedes comprobar [en este link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2ec5/5/0)

Comment: Perfecto, lo has clavado. Por rizar el rizo necesitaría que me mostrara también (además de lo que ya mostraba) todos los clientes que contienen 1 y a su vez tienen el campo asociado vacío.

Comment: Agregale esto:  `union all select * from prueba where asociado = 0`  puedes ver el ejemplo  [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/580c3/2/1), si el campo asociado lo dejas null en vez de `where asociado = 0`  utliza  `where asociado is null`